# Optimized Garbled Circuit Algorithmic Description

Tags: algorithm-design, garbled-circuits, optimization

The [Garbled Circuit (GC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbled_circuit) is now over thirty years old, and many optimization methodologies have been proposed, including point-and-permute, row-reduction, free-XOR, fixed-key blockcipher, half-and.

But, after Googling papers and forums, I can't find any concrete algorithmic descriptions which includes all of these optimizations. Does anyone know the exact descriptions of optimized GCs?

I ask because I need to implement the algorithm for personal use.

Answer (score 2):

Not all optimizations of garbled circuits are compatible with each other. Are you interested in implementing *all* of the different combinations? If not, the Half Gates paper already gives a formal description of the scheme, which includes point-permute, fixed-key block cipher, free-XOR. This should represent the state-of-the-art combination of GC optimizations. There is a good implementation of half-gates in the [Ivory project](https://github.com/ladnir/Ivory-Runtime).

Comment: Thanks for your response. After looking at the paper talking about half-and, it is clear that it deploys almost all optimizations that can be integrated. Indeed, the final scheme of Half-And is really hard to understand for me. Do you have any good explanation on the constructions of its T_Gc and W_Gc as well as T_Ec and W_Ec?